# What exception should be used in Java when a file can be read but the file's data is improperly formatted?

Tags: java, exception

When a specified file has been read successfully, but the data within the file is improper, such as malformed XML, or an ini file that specifies the wrong variables or is missing a section, or something like that, what should of exception should be used in that case?

Does it make sense to use an IOException with a detailed exception message, or should another kind of exception be used? There doesn't appear to be a good exception type for this sort of event within the standard library.

Comment: If you can't find an exception that suits your needs, use your own exception type.

Comment: If your code says that the data is improper, then you should create your own Exception and throw it. Otherwise you are using a library that tells you that the data is not well formed probably by throwing an exception

Comment: Most probably some subclass of IOException, such as CharConversionExceptin or StreamCorruptedException, or one you create yourself.  (You know how to find the subclasses of IOException, right?)

Comment: Depends on whom the message is intended for.  You can use `IOException` with a detail message, or make your own subclass of `Exception`, `RuntimeException`, or some other appropriate sublass.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to find a class's subclasses :P  The closest thing to my particular situation would be the InvalidPropertiesFormatException, since I'm dealing with an INI file that needs to have several properties each within a specific bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a style question as 'technically' it doesn't matter what type of exception you throw; it could be a [`java.awt.FontFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontFormatException.html), [`javax.management.modelmbean.XMLParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/modelmbean/XMLParseException.html) or even just a standard [`java.lang.Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) with whatever extra info you put in it.

That being said, as others have suggested, it's probably a better choice to 'roll your own':

```
public class InvalidFormatting extends java.lang.Throwable
{
    /** The underlying error of this instance */
    public final static String Error = "An invalid format has been detected";

    /** Create a new {@code InvalidFormatting} exception */
    public InvalidFormatting() {
        super(InvalidFormatting.Error);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new {@code InvalidFormatting} exception with additional information
     *
     * @param additionalMsg The additional information to append
     */
    public InvalidFormatting(String additionalMsg) {
        super(InvalidFormatting.Error + "\n" + additionalMsg);
    }
}
```

Then it can be used as such

```
throw new InvalidFormatting("here's some extra info");
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `IOException` -- the file has been opened and read successfully; the problem is its content. You could throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, or create your own exception type.